# NoClassDefFoundError on ComputeClassWriter using Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipselink 2.4.2 and am deploying an EAR on Weblogic 10.3.5.  I am getting the following error on every Entity when I try to deploy:
**The exception was: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/weaving/ComputeClassWriter**
I can clearly see that the ComputeClassWriter class is in the eclipselink 2.4.2 jar and that jar is in the appropriate lib directory of the EAR.  Has anyone come across this before?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using the `Link with Editor` with the exception on your console. It will link you to from where the class is actually loading.

Answer (score 0):

It's happen the same to me.

[EL Warning]: weaver: 2014-02-17 12:59:36.897--ServerSession(285072714)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Weaver encountered an exception while trying to weave class net.xxx.MyEntity  The exception was: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/weaving/ComputeClassWriter

Comment: your response should contain a solution

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently after upgrade EclipseLink from 2.3.0 to 2.4.2 on WebLogic 10.3.6 running in development mode with jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0
Strangely this error does not happen on production mode WebLogic with same environment.
After some research and test I found that the startup script in 'commEnv.cmd' adds '-Xverify:none' to JAVA_OPTIONS when weblogic works with jrockit in development mode:

```
:oracle
if "%PRODUCTION_MODE%" == "true" goto oracle_prod_mode
set JAVA_VM=-jrockit
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms128m -Xmx256m
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xverify:none
goto continue
:oracle_prod_mode
set JAVA_VM=-jrockit
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms128m -Xmx256m
goto continue
```

After removing '-Xverify:none', weaving works without error.

I assume this could be a complex class loading and class verify bug.